# How to connect to wifi by MAC address?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, network-programming

I have a few wifi networks

[image]

But the problem is that all of them have same ssids, so i decided to connect by MAC

```
 WiFiAdapter firstAdapter = null;
            var accessRes = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("access res:"+accessRes);
            var result = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector());
            
            if (result.Count >= 1)
            {
                firstAdapter = await WiFiAdapter.FromIdAsync(result[0].Id);
                await firstAdapter.ScanAsync();
                var wifis = firstAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks;

           
                PasswordCredential creds = new PasswordCredential();
                creds.Password = "pw";
                WiFiAvailableNetwork wifi = wifis.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Bssid == "mac");
                var res =  await firstAdapter.ConnectAsync(wifi, WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic, creds);
                Console.WriteLine($"Result: {res.ConnectionStatus}");
            }
```

But now my problem is that Windows after I connected to network that I want, it just change it to network with same ssid but better signal, any ideas how I can disable this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is a system behavior.

Currently, UWP has no relevant API to prevent the system from selecting better signal networks in the same ssid network.

Comment: But maybe I can manually disable service which do this?

Comment: Have you tried to modify the property `Roaming Aggressiveness` of the network adapter and set it to `disabled`?